# J5. Activate Tab key and Indent in Codemirror in custom component

Tags: custom-component, editor, joomla-5.x

Codemirror v6 looks like not so easy to configure as previous versions. In my custom component I get codemirror editor with this code who use for options sintax like v5:

```
$editor = Editor::getInstance('codemirror');
$options = array(
    'syntax' => 'php', 
    'mode' => 'application/x-httpd-php', 
    'indentUnit' => '4',
    'indentWithTabs' => true,
    'smartIndent' => true
    );

...

<?= $editor->display('myEditorId', 'My custom content', '100%', '900', '300', '3', false, 'myEditorId', null, null, $options); ?>
```

Tab key doesn't work as I expected in a code editor because leave the editor and direct the focus to the next control. I would like to configure codemirror inserting a tab (4 spaces) pressing Tab key, and remove a tab pressing Ctrl+Tab.

Also, autoindent works but with 2 spaces (default configuration), and I need to configure it to 4 espaces.

Please, someone have configured Codemirror with these parameters? How could I do it?